# Is it possible to remove FOR SYSTEM_TIME dinamically in a query for a system-versioned table?

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I have this query to get data from a system-versioned table (SQL Server 2016 Standard):

```
Select * 
From [dbo].[Department] FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2021-01-31 15:54:46.2079370'
```

Sometimes, I would need to execute the query without the FOR SYSTEM-TIME. Is it possible to remove FOR SYSTEM_TIME dinamically? Something similar to this one: (it doesn't work)

```
Declare @var1 as int = 1
    Select * 
    from [TEST]..[Department] 
        CASE 
            When @var1 = 1 THEN
                FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2021-01-31 15:54:46.2079370'
        END CASE
```

Comment: If you don't need the `FOR SYSTEM_TIME` syntax, why is it in your query at all? This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Otherwise, why not parametrise the `SYSTEM_TIME` value, and assign the system time (for example `SYSUTCDATETIME`) to the parameter if it's `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Larnu. It can be done by this way: `Declare @myDate as datetime2 = GETDATE()
Select * from [dbo].[Department] 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @myDate`

Comment: I would use `sysdatetime` or similar, as `GETDATE()` returns a `datetime`, not a `datetime2(7)`.